# find $\int^6_0f(x)dx$ by definition , $f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f(x)=\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\rfloor$,
>
> Is $f(x)$ integrable at $[0,6]$?
>
> If so, find $\int^6_0f(x)dx$ by definition.

---

The function is integratable because it is bounded and it has a finite number of points which are not continuous in $[0,6]$.

So first we need to divide the interval into even parts, I did that by $\frac{6-0}{n}=\frac{6}{n}=\Delta x$.

And then choose the integration points: let $x_k^* \in [0,6]$ and the points are $x_k^*=1+\frac{5n-1}{n}$.

Then calculate the summation:
$$S_n=\sum^n_{k=1}f(x_k^*)\cdot \Delta x = \sum^n_{k=1} \left\lfloor\frac{x_k^* }{3}\right\rfloor \cdot \frac{6}{n} = \sum^n_{k=1} \left\lfloor\frac{6-\frac{1}{n}}{3}\right\rfloor \cdot \frac{6}{n} = \sum^n_{k=1} \left\lfloor\frac{6n-1 }{3n}\right\rfloor \cdot \frac{6}{n}  $$

Now if I calculate the limit of $S_N$ as $n$ approaches infinity I get that the answer is $0$ which is wrong according to the book it is supposed to be $3$ but it only provides the final answer.

Can anyone give me any tips and hints on that? I find this topic complicated.

Hopefully my translations are understandable. Thank you.

EDIT - my answer is also wrong even if I use $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x^*=a+ \Delta x \cdot k$

Comment: $f(x)=\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\rfloor$ is discontinuous at multiples of $3$ such as $0,3,6$ so why not split the integral into the piecewise continuous parts and then add the (two) results together?

Comment: Your definition of $x^{*}_k$ is different to what you are using in the $S_n$. You are also summing over $k$, but $k$ is no where to be found in your sum. Are these typos?

Comment: @Henry so make a piecewise function where we assume the point $t$ is one time $0 \leq t <3$ , $3 \leq t <6$ and for the last $t=6$?

Comment: @NiveaNutella why different ? $6-\frac{1}{n}$=$1+\frac{5n-1}{n}$

Comment: @Adamrk Yes - and $\int^6_6 \cdots dx =0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by your definition $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{6}{n}$, so $x_k = \frac{k \Delta x}{n}$. $k$ starts from $0$ to $n$. so the sum would be:
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k)\Delta x = \sum_{k=0}^n \left\lfloor \frac{6k}{3n} \right\rfloor \frac{6}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \left\lfloor \frac{2k}{n} \right\rfloor \frac{6}{n}
$$
$2k/n$ is less than $1$ if $k<\lceil n/2 \rceil$, so $\lfloor \frac{2k}{n} \rfloor$ is zero. only nonzero elements are for $  \lceil n/2 \rceil \leq k \leq n$ and $\left\lfloor \frac{2k}{n} \right\rfloor$ is just 1. so the summation becomes :
$$ 
S_n = \sum_{k=\lceil n/2 \rceil}^n  \frac{6}{n} = \frac{6}{n} \sum_{k=\lceil n/2 \rceil}^n1 = \frac{6}{n} ( n - \left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil).
$$
if you take limit for $n \rightarrow \infty$ , you get:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n = \frac{6}{n} \left(\frac{n}{2}\right) = 3.
$$
you can find this value easily by linearity of integral:
$$
\int_0^6 \left\lfloor \frac{x}{3} \right\rfloor dx = \int_0^3 0 dx + \int_3^6 1 dx =\int_3^6 dx = 6-3 = 3.    
$$

you didn't use correct formula for $x_k$ because there is no $k$ in your formula and hence in your sum!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! , can you please tell me why did you check when $\frac{2k}{n}$ is less than 1? as a user here stated we have 3 options because of the floor value and the possible values of the function are $0,1,2$ what about those values?

Comment: Your welcome. $\left \lfloor \frac{x}{3} \right \rfloor$ for $x \in [0,6]$ is a piecewise constant function. its value is $0$ if $x \in [0,3)$. it is 1 if $x \in [3,6)$. and it is 2 for $x=6$. so yes it has three possible values but its value is $2$ for just one point. the value of one point doesn't affect value of integral. so what i did was actually dividing the sum for two values $0$ and $1$. and you need to just compute the sum for intreval that $f(x)$ is 1, that is $[3,6)$, or in summation it is $k=\{\lceil n/2 \rceil, \lceil n/2 \rceil + 1, \dots , n\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much , but I noticed something you said  $  \lceil n/2 \rceil \leq k \leq n$ and $\left\lfloor \frac{2k}{n} \right\rfloor$ is just 1 but what if $k=n$? then the value is $2$ maybe you meant $<$ and not $\leq$?

Comment: yes as i said the value in $k=n$ is 2. but that's just 1 points in $\mathbb{R}$ if you take limit for $n \rightarrow \infty$ its value doesn't matter. you can also take $k \in \{ \lceil n/2 \rceil, \dots,n-1\}$ . the value of $ (n-1 - \lceil n/2 \rceil)/n$  is equal to $1/2$ in limit and you get same result.

Comment: Thank you! all clear now